# What's the song in Castle in the Sky when the castle is destroyed?

Tags: music, castle-in-the-sky

I would like to know the name of the music in the anime movie *Castle in The Sky* at 1 hour 55 minutes when the castle is destroyed.

I tried to Shazam it but didn’t work out

Does anyone know the name?

Answer (score 1):

The song that is played at 1 hour 55 minutes is named *The Destruction of Laputa* (Rapyuta No Hokai). It has a duration of 2:00 and is performed by *The Suginami Children's Choir* (Suginami Jidō Gasshō-dan)[¹](https://www.discogs.com/Joe-Hisaishi-Castle-In-The-Sky-Original-Soundtrack/release/4570921).